# Definite clause grammar in Prolog - Or statement

Tags: parsing, prolog, dcg

What would be the best way to define a phrase that can describe an adverb in either one of two ways?

Could you just say:

1. `adverb_phrase(N,adv(N,Adv)) --> Way 1.`
2. `adverb_phrase(N,adv(N,Adv)) --> Way 2.`

I've tried doing this but I get variables (like `_G12345`) in the output, which doesn't look right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**, what you show is definitely a **valid** way to state alternatives in DCGs.

There are other options too. Here are some:

## 1. Your version

This is your version, only extended to a somewhat more complete example:

```
adverb_phrase(N, adv(N,Adv)) --> adv1(Adv).
adverb_phrase(N, adv(N,Adv)) --> adv2(Adv).

adv1(likely)  --> [].
adv2(happily) --> [].
```

Example query and answer:

```
?- phrase(adverb_phrase(N,A), Ls).
A = adv(N, likely),
Ls = [] ;
A = adv(N, happily),
Ls = [].
```

Two solutions are found on backtracking. The variable `N` also occurs in the query. I do not know why you introduced it, and if you do not need it, you can simply omit it.

## 2. More compact

Using different rules to denote alternatives is straight-forward. Note that you can **refactor** the code to make it more compact:

```
adverb_phrase(N, adv(N,Adv)) --> adv(Adv).

adv(likely)  --> [].
adv(happily) --> [].
```

In this case, I have simply used **the same** nonterminal to denote the alternatives.

## 3. Using `('|')//2`

Note that there are also **other ways** to denote alternatives. An elegant way is to use `('|')//2`, in analogy to how alternatives are often indicated in other formalisms.

For example, you can write your initial example as:

```
adverb_phrase(N, adv(N,Adv)) --> adv1(Adv) | adv2(Adv).

adv1(likely)  --> [].
adv2(happily) --> [].
```

Instead of `('|')//2`, you can also use `(;)//2` if you want to, in analogy to plain Prolog.

The shown variants yield exactly the same answers. The version you choose depends on several factors, for example: Are you using the DCG more in the "grammar" or more in the "monad" sense.

For your specific case, version 2 seems a good fit from a first impression.

Note that neither of these options is an "or *statement*". We call these **nonterminals**!

Comment: Thanks for elaborating on that for me!